# Can RealmCollectionChange be used as a way of syncing data back to server?

Tags: ios, synchronization, realm

I noticed that in Realm Swift, there is a RealmCollectionChange
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-notifications

It seems to contain the objects that have changed. Can I use that notification block to add code to sync the data back to a back end database?
Is the notification block running on the main queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you can use the provided notification mechanisms to propagate changes to a server. You should make sure though, that your requests to the server doesn't cause new changes once the server responds, otherwise you can run into a situation where you would be constantly notified about new updates, as also seen in the related docs section [User-Driven Updates](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#user-driven-updates).

The notification block is ran on the thread on which you add it. But these APIs are only available to auto-updating Realms which require a runloop. By default only the main thread has a runloop, if you don't run any additional yourself on dedicated background threads.

Be aware that synchronizing is a non-trivial problem and using these notifications alone won't give you a full solution for every challenge involved into that problem space.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that problem too. The typical use case is multi device synchronization, which is very tricky indeed.